# eclipse single tab for navigating through java classes

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any way to configure Eclipse such that when I am in one file (Java class in my case) and I f3 into another class, to prevent it from opening in a new tab?  I am ending up with a bagillion different tabs.  I want the new file to appear in the tab where the old on was (think replace)

Comment: Tip: use ctrl + left/right arrow to navigate through your navigation history.

Comment: There are some settings in the Preferences in 'General > Editors'

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by enabling "Close editors automatically" while also limiting the "Number of opened editors before closing" to 1. It's technically not *one single tab* because a new editor is opened, but it should still fit your needs.

See "Preferences > General > Editors":

[image: screenshot of preference page]

If you want certain editors to still be kept open, you can *pin* them via the new toolbar icon that appears after checking above setting:

[image]

(Version: Eclipse Mars.2)

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any way to do this so if I have 4 tabs open, but I only want this feature to apply for one tab?  For instance, I have 4 tabs open, but when I'm in one tab, and I am opening a new file from within that tab, I want the new file to appear in the same tab, without closing the other tabs.  So the end result will be 4 tabs, with the new file open in one tab, and the file from which I opened the new file no longer there.  Is this a possibility?

Comment: You cannot restrict this behaviour to single tabs, but you can _pin_ single tabs to leave them open (actually the opposite of what you're thinking, but might potentially work). See my updated answer.